# Intermittent IIS Connection close issue

Tags: iis-7.5

really odd one here.

I have a website which runs on IIS fine most of the time. On some occasions though I get a white 404 page with the text:

Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Running fiddler I can see the following http headers:

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 21:25:01 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 315

So a "connection close" error seems to be happening intermittently.

A couple of refreshes later the page loads fine with the following headers:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 15:53:56 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "02d1f3c09fcc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
mycustomheader: 01
Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 21:25:24 GMT
Content-Length: 16307

I notice that the 404 header doesn't have custom http header response which I've added as part of my debug steps. In IIS if an error is being served by a specific web should it not have the custom header aswell?

Anyone know why certain http requests would intermittently be closed by IIS?

Thanks,

Ed

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Would be nice to know if you came across a solution. I have a similar problem.

Comment: what kind of content is this?

Comment: Wow. This is old, and you probably don't care anymore.

Anyhow, the problem isn't that the connection is being closed; that's just a 404 error. From your response headers, it's obvious that your code isn't even being touched. The response is coming from the lower-level HTTP subsystem; IIS isn't even getting to the Asp.Net pipeline. For whatever the reason, it's not finding your .aspx file. I would suggest you look at the filesystem/OS level for answers.

Answer (score -1):

Have a nice day.

Please, have a minute to check the next site.
That's important to solve the problem, because you're not giving any Event Log details.

Let us know if this helps you to solve the problem.
Thank you.

https://www.leansentry.com/Guide/IIS-AspNet-Hangs

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, please [provide context around links](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. If possible summarise or quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. - Also: Please try to take note of the publication date of questions, asking the Original Poster to perform debugging steps 7 years later is unlikely to generate a response...